# how to update local git when I have pushed from another machine?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I setup a git repo on school machine and then clone the same repo on another home machine. I have commited and pushed on the home machine now I want to update the change to the school machine. What should I do? I tried `git remote update` but it didn't update when I checked the files.

Comment: If you pushed, isn't the school repo already up to date?  Or do you have a third repository that is the remote for both?

Comment: Which repo is the authoritative one?

Comment: The school repo is the original, i then worked from the home repo and made changes and then pushed.

Answer (score 1):

you did it wrong :)

if you are using repository not as a bare repository on a school machine you need to

git reset --hard

after pushing to it, because you just update ref's not a working copy

much more better is using bare repository and pull/push to it from other machine/repository
[Git on server](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just execute this command in your school machine:

git pull origin master

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with `bitbucket`, I'm going to make the following assumptions.  If any of these assumptions are not correct, clarify in your question and I will update this answer.

- there are three (3) repositories total

  - one on `bitbucket`
  - a clone of the `bitbucket` repository on the school machine
  - a clone of the `bitbucket` repository on your home system.
- on the home clone, steps similar to:

  - 
  - `git add <changes>`
  - `git commit -m '<message>'`
  - `git push <remote> <branch>`
- on the school clone

  - `git remote update`

The `git remote update` fetched the changes in all remotes, so if the changes pushed by the home repository are on the same remote they have been loaded into the repository on the school system.

The key here is the repository is the `.git` folder, so the refs in it were updated -- but the working copy was not.  In order to update the working copy you will need to merge the changes fetched to the local repository with the working directory.  This is done with a `git merge <options>`.

---

If my assumptions, based on your tags, is not correct and there are only the two repositories; school and home.  Then you need to `git merge <options>` to bring the changes into your working copy, unless you have local changes as well; in which case do something similar to the following if

```
git stash
git merge <options>
git stash pop
```

At this point resolve any conflicts between the local changes popped from the stash and commit.

If you don't want to keep the changes in your local copy, you can return the working copy to the state of the last commit with a `git reset --hard`.

---

One final word of caution, don't push into a non-bare repository if you can avoid it -- and you generally can.  It is much better for the school repository to pull (fetch/merge) the changes from the home repository than it is for the home repository to push to the school repository.